# google app engine get_serving_url() is not defined

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, python-imaging-library

It seems like an easy problem yet I cant figure it out:

I call `get_serving_url()` function in my code and get en error:

> NameError: global name 'get_serving_url' is not defined

my import statement currently looks like:
from google.appengine.api import images

before i tried various "from PIL import Image" and got import errors.
i recently installed the PIL library

I have site-packages and PIL folder on my python path

how do I make `get_serving_url()` work?

Answer (score 5):

```
from google.appengine.api import images
```

^ Is correct.

Then use `images.get_serving_url()` to make it look for the function in the module you just imported.

If you don't prefix it with `images.` it will look in the `globals()` in your current module, when Python can't find it there it raises `NameError`.

Comment: @user1167937, you can mark the answer as solved if it indeed solved your problem :)